# Node JS: как передать req, res в пользовательскую функцию?

Tags: node.js, express

Подскажите, пожалуйста, могу ли я в NodeJS, используя Express, передавать `req` и  `res` из мидлвар функции в обычную и проводить с ними разные манипуляции? Например.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    let param1 = 'test';
    myTestFunc(param1, req, res);
    res.render('login');
});

const myTestFunc = (param1, req, res) => {
    req.session.param = param1;
    res.cookie('test', param1, { maxAge:1000000, httpOnly: true });
}
```

Идея в том, чтобы сгруппировать методы для простоты восприятия и уменьшения объема кода. Например, есть мидлвары, где нужно сделать одно и тоже - добавить в сессию ID пользователя, токен и т.д. Мне было бы удобнее создать отдельную функцию, передать туда `req` и  `res` и что-ниубдь с ними делать. Я бы мог вызывать этот метод из любой мидлвар-функции.

Правильно ли это?

Comment: Можно конечно. Другое дело, что это немного не по «экспессовски».

Comment: @AlexeyTen не по «экспессовски» - это как? Как правильно, рациональней?

Comment: А откуда берётся param1?

Comment: @AlexeyTen param1 получается путем await вызова другой функции до вызова функции myTestFunc(), Я привел для примера. Это может быть значение, которое я получаю из базы данных, например, ID пользователя или что угодно.